# Laravel - what does this bit of code mean?

Tags: laravel

```
<div class ="form-group">
   {!! Html::decode(Form::label('first_name','<strong>First Name:</strong>')) !!}
  {{Form::text('first_name', old('first_name'), ['class' => 'form-control '.($errors->has('first_name') ? 'is-invalid': ''), 'placeholder' => '', 'required'])}}
</div>
```

What does this bit of the code mean?

```
($errors->has('first_name') ? 'is-invalid': '')
```

Answer (score 5):

"If the `first_name` field has errors, print `is-invalid`, otherwise print nothing."

Basically, it's applying the `is-invalid` class to fields that are invalid (per the Laravel validator). In Bootstrap, this typically turns the field red so the user can see it's incorrect.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense

Answer (score 1):

That is called a `Ternary`. Shorthand for `if/else`

Here is post on those that is helpful:
https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators